# Is it safe to let users enter custom regex patterns?

Tags: regex, postgresql, groovy, full-text-search

I have an application which takes text files as input and parses text from them and stores them in the DB. After this, the users can look for certain keywords to see if they match any of the text from the text files that were uploaded.

I want the users to not only be able to enter keywords but also make up their own regex patterns which the system will use to search for stuff. The custom regex patterns will have a property `isRegex` set to true.

Hence, I am searching the text in my code like this:

```
if (keyword.isRegex) {
 if (text ==~ /${keyword}/) {
   m = text =~ /${keyword}/
   m.each {println "Found ${it}"
 }
}
else {
 if (text ==~ /\b${keyword}\b/) {
   m = text =~ /\b${keyword}\b/
   m.each {prinltn "Found ${it}"
 }
}
```

**Questions**

- Is it safe to let users enter their own custom regex? If not, what are some measure I can take to avoid security issues.
- Is my approach to finding text ok? I know there are full text search solutions or DBs but I don't need all the features they provide. Would I be better off using PostgreSQL for full text search? Does it provide regex expressions?

Comment: How end user knows regex pattern? Are you giving them a training?

Comment: assuming they know how to write regex. this feature will only be given to  very selected users (4 or 5)

Comment: in that case provide some help content or links aside it. Still you need to validate each regex pattern. you can't trust it.

Answer (score 0):

In a naive implementation, no, it is not safe. There is an attack that people can perform on a regular expression called a [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS). You can also read more about it on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS). It is a denial of service done by consuming computational resources, which could prevent other requests being responded to.

A ReDoS can be prevented if you cap your regex execution time using `statement_timeout`, which can be set with `set statement_timeout to 10000`. Replace `10000` with a timeout that is more relevant to your environment.

You could also consider using the `LIKE` operator to select based on a keyword. Searching based on a keyword is typically more user-friendly than a regular expression, and you don't have to worry about setting a timeout.

Comment: but if I use the `LIKE` operator then the users can't enter their own regex patterns right?

Comment: Correct. It's an alternative, but not a replacement. Like I said above, if you limit the execution time of the regex, then that will mitigate the attack vector.

Comment: Simply setting a `statement_timeout` is usually sufficient to deal with ReDoS etc.